# TableView cell not resizing after changing imageView height constraint based on Image height downloaded using SDWebImage (AUTOLAYOUT)

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview, sdwebimage

I'm using autolayout.This is my code using it under `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.chatImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: newsFeed.postImage!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default_profile"), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> Void in

                let height = ((image?.size.height)! / (image?.size.width)!) * (tableView.bounds.width - 16)
                cell.chatImageHeight.constant = height
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
```

The cell doesn't resize. It only resizes after scrolling. What should I do?
Since I'm using autolayout, I'm not implementing `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. I've already mentioned `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and `estimatedRowHeight`.

Comment: wait, so are you using uitableviewautomaticdimension or not? I'm not sure where you mentioned it.

Comment: @user3353890 I've already mentioned it in view did load. The problem is arising only when I try to update the constraint inside the block.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to call self.view.setNeedsLayout() this will make the whole view to layout fixing the constraints

```
cell.chatImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: newsFeed.postImage!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default_profile"), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> Void in

                let height = ((image?.size.height)! / (image?.size.width)!) * (tableView.bounds.width - 16)
                cell.chatImageHeight.constant = height

                self.view.setNeedsLayout()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            })
```

Comment: mmm, can you increase estimatedRowHeight

or try this which should work
--------------------------------------------
cell.chatImageHeight.constant = height
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded)            tableView?.beginUpdates()
            tableView?.endUpdates()

Comment: I've tried tableview.beginUpdates and endUpdates but this is not a right way and the app will crash eventually because it is being called again and again in cell for row at indexPath.

Comment: Any news about that? I'm facing the same issue :/